# Iniciante com firebase

Tags: javascript, json, ionic, app, firebase

Quero implementar o firebase no meu aplicativo (ionic).

[image: index]

[image: app]

[image: controller]

Quando eu testo da uma mensagem:

> Unknown provider: $firebaseArrayProvider <- $firebaseArray <- LoginCtrl

1. É melhor eu declarar minhas configurações do firebase no "app" ou "index"? Eu vi das duas formas de fazer na web.
2. Gostaria de criar uma tabela contendo as informações do usuário no firebase como: email, nome, senha, info de cadastro em geral.
3. Cada usuário teria relacionado com suas respectivas contas suas mensagens enviadas e recebidas.

*Pessoal, me ajudem, já li bastante coisa a respeito mas realmente estou com dificuldades nessa parte!*

Comment: vc injetou o Firebase no seu app.js?

Comment: Boa tarde @DiegoAugusto, injetar seria instalar e no projeto e linka? eu fiz isso já. :(

Comment: Injetar seria isso:  `angular.module('myApp', ['firebase'])`

Comment: Fiz isso já! `angular.module('starter', [
   'ionic', 'ngCordova', 'firebase',...`

Comment: Já tentou atualizar a biblioteca angularFire?

Comment: Tenta trocar sua declaração do angular-fire no index.html pra isso: 
`<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.1.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>` e veja se funciona

Comment: Eu baixei ontem através do "npm install" o angularfire e firebase. Copiei o angularfire.min.js e o firebase.js pra minha pasta JS do projeto. Acredito que esteja atualizado né?

Comment: troquei minha declaração e apareceu isso: ionic.bundle.js:13441 Uncaught Error:[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebase due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Nem sempre a ultima versão é baixada. De acordo com a documentação é só seguir esses mesmos passos. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47523/discussion-between-diegoaugusto-and-henrique-gusmao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode atualizar a versão do angular-fire, provavelmente a versão que você está utilizando não suporta o `$firebaseArray`.

Tente trocar a importação das suas libs para essas:

```
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.0/firebase.js"></script>

<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Se funcionar você pode baixar as libs atualizadas e importa-las como antigamente.

> É melhor eu declarar minhas configurações do firebase no "app" ou
>   "index"? Eu vi das duas formas de fazer na web.

Acredito que isso seja mais questão de "boas práticas", eu particularmente sempre utilizo no `app.js` pois dessa forma o projeto fica mais organizado

Refêrencia: [Quickstart | AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md)

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado @DiegoAugusto !